# Make a payment with encrypted card data

Tags: payment-gateway, adyen

how to get the Following data from $_POST['encrypted-data']

EncryptedCardNumber

ExpiryMonth

ExpiryYear

EncryptedSecurityCode

I passed one  Input "encrypted-data" but I want
EncryptedCardNumber
,ExpiryMonth
,ExpiryYear
,EncryptedSecurityCode

Client side

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.adyen.com/hpp/cse/js/HWC324534556545.shtml"></script>

  <form method="POST" action="payment.php" id="adyen-encrypted-form">
    <input placeholder="number" type="text" size="20" data-encrypted-name="number" value="2223520443560010" />
    <input placeholder="holderName" type="text" size="20" data-encrypted-name="holderName" value="Ashok" />
    <input placeholder="expiryMonth" type="text" size="2" data-encrypted-name="expiryMonth" value="10" />
    <input placeholder="expiryYear" type="text" size="4" data-encrypted-name="expiryYear" value="2024" />
    <input placeholder="cvc" type="text" size="4" data-encrypted-name="cvc" value="737" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'); ?>" data-encrypted-name="generationtime"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
 </form>

<script>
    // The form element to encrypt.
    var form = document.getElementById('adyen-encrypted-form');

    var options = {};
    // Bind encryption options to the form.

    options.name = "encrypted-data";
    options.onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        form.submit();  
    };

 var key = "MY Key";
var result = adyen.encrypt.createEncryptedForm(form, key, options);
</script>
```

processing payment payment.php

```
<?php
//echo $_POST['encrypted-data'];

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new \Adyen\Client();

$client->setXApiKey("my api key");
$client->setEnvironment(\Adyen\Environment::TEST);
$client->setTimeout(30);
$service = new \Adyen\Service\Checkout\PaymentsApi($client);

$requestOptions['idempotencyKey'] = "c3276329-1bb1-47dc-a19a-5cc87f79de11";
// Create a PaymentMethod object.
$paymentMethod = new \Adyen\Model\Checkout\CheckoutPaymentMethod();
$paymentMethod
    ->setType("scheme")
    ->setEncryptedCardNumber("test_4111111111111111")
    ->setEncryptedExpiryMonth("test_03")
    ->setEncryptedExpiryYear("test_2030")
    ->setEncryptedSecurityCode("test_737");

// Create an Amount object.
$amount = new \Adyen\Model\Checkout\Amount();
$amount
    ->setValue(10)
    ->setCurrency("EUR");

// Create the PaymentRequest object.
$paymentRequest = new \Adyen\Model\Checkout\PaymentRequest();
$paymentRequest
    ->setMerchantAccount("myMerchantAccountCOM")
    ->setPaymentMethod($paymentMethod)
    ->setAmount($amount)
    ->setReference("payment-test")
    ->setReturnUrl("");

// Make a /payments request.
$result = $service->payments($paymentRequest, $requestOptions);
//$pspReference = $result.pspReference;
```

How to replace this example data

test_4111111111111111

test_03

test_2030

test_737

with the crypted data Entered by client

thanks

Answer (score 1):

When performing a card payment with Adyen you have 2 options.

Use the Adyen client-side [solutions](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/cards/#which-platform-are-you-integrating) that securely collect and encrypt card information. You can find an example in PHP in the [adyen-examples](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-php-online-payments) GitHub repository.
In your example above you would integrate the Dropin in the client side.

Make a payment by sending the raw (unencrypted) card information: in this case you need to be fully [PCI compliant](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/pci-dss-compliance-guide/).
In your example above you would fill the data in the form with the information entered by the shopper.

Comment: ,Please  if you have PHP native example raw (unencrypted) card information, I do not Use Laravel ,